# WPF Binding DataTrigger To A Different Property

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Teleric RadGrid View like this that's bound to a property called Load:

```
    <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="myRadGridView"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Load}">
```

I have a DataTrigger for that same grid that I want to bind to a property called checkColor which is in the same class as the RadGridView's Load property. I think this isn't working because both properties are in the same class? What would be the correct syntax?

```
        <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding checkColor}" Value="true">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style> 
        </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
```

Comment: _"I think this isn't working because both properties are in the same class?"_ -- why would that be the case? It seems more likely to me that the problem is all you've done in the above is declare a `Style` resource, but in the `Resources` of the object where you want to apply it. That won't work. You need to declare it in one of that object's _parent_ objects. If that's not the issue, please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: If I move the <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" /> line up above the data trigger it applies, so the style is being applied.  (The style sits inside my RadGridView definition.)  I've set a break point in my checkColor property and it's never being run. I think it can't find it--is there a way to confirm that?

Comment: Found another way around. Thanks Peter for the comment.

Comment: Note: found that the info on bad bindings was in the "Immediate Window" rather than the "Output Window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.s. revisited this and finally found the real solution.

1) Added an item to the Window pointing at the class I wanted to reference.

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyClass"
```

2) Created a static resource to it on a parent component:

```
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <local:Changes x:Key="MyViewModel"/>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
```

3) Set my setter binding to point at it:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}, Path=checkColor}"/>
```

---

Old "Solution":

Ended up solving the problem by putting the data the checkColor function was going to return into a new column in the DataTable that the RadGridView is bound to. Since columns are part of the RadGridView's binding scope I could bind it to the DataTrigger like this:

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding checkColorDataColumn}" Value="1">
            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </DataTrigger.Setters>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
```